# Who is Immanuel?

Tags: bible, life-of-jesus, christology

In Isaiah 7:13-17

> 13 Then Isaiah said, “Hear now, you house of David! Is it not enough to try the patience of humans? Will you try the patience of my God also? 14 Therefore the Lord himself will give you[c] a sign: The virgin[d] will conceive and give birth to a son, and[e] will call him Immanuel.[f] 15 He will be eating curds and honey when he knows enough to reject the wrong and choose the right, 16 for before the boy knows enough to reject the wrong and choose the right, the land of the two kings you dread will be laid waste. 17 The LORD will bring on you and on your people and on the house of your father a time unlike any since Ephraim broke away from Judah—he will bring the king of Assyria.”

The name Immanuel is used here to refer, ostensibly, to Jesus. However, Jesus is only confirmed by Matthew indirectly in Matthew 1:23-24

> 22 All this took place to fulfill what the Lord had said through the prophet: 23 “The virgin will conceive and give birth to a son, and they will call him Immanuel”[g] (which means “God with us”).

Is there another reference that makes this illusion more clear (possibly with historical significance)? Do the other gospel accounts support this conclusion?

HT: Sklivvz for asking this in a comment on [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/how-do-we-know-mary-was-a-virgin-at-the-time-of-jesus-conception/2292#2292) answer.

Answer (score 13):

Immanuel is a title that means "God with us".  Some people have suggested that since Jesus was named "Jesus", then "Immanuel" does not refer to Him.  This is akin to claiming that the titles "King of Kings" and "Lord of Lords" don't apply to Jesus, because He was named "Jesus" and not "King of Kings" or "Lord of Lords".

God the Son, the Second Person of the Trinity, is co-eternal and co-existent with the Father and the Spirit.  When God the Son (The Word) entered into His creation, He was given the name Jesus (Yeshua in Hebrew).  "Yeshua" means, "The Lord (God) saves" because Jesus (God the Son) was saving His people from their sins.  The name Jesus indicates His mission.  The title "Immanuel" indicates that He was God "with us" and walked among us.

Comment: This is illustrated well by [Isaiah 9:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%209:6&version=NIV)

Comment: Good point, Richard.  It actually says a "son" will be "God with us".

Comment: It illustrates the "he will be called" as a title rather a name.  I'd write my own answer, but you've covered most of it. ...Well, and I'm not quite up for it.

Comment: So you are claiming the Bible is mistranslated? In the passage cited it is quite clear that Immanuel is used as name, and not an appellative.

Comment: No, I'm not.  Quite to the contrary, it's not "quite clear" that Immanuel would be His actual name.  If you combine this with Isaiah 9:6, it would mean He would have a really long name--"Immanual Mighty God Everlasting Father Wonderful Counselor Prince of Peace".  No mistranslation, but definitely a misunderstanding.